# Loop through CTE results and run a query for each

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a SQL query/procedure that would loop through records the CTE brings back.

The CTE would return table names of tables that have to have the queries executed to.

Example CTE Results:

```
op2018al
op290717al
```

and more...

The query that would need to be run for the two tables from CTE would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Records_missing
FROM scheme./** tables form the CTE **/ a WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM table_a b WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE a.COLUMN = b.COLUMN
        )
```

I believe that this would have to be a stored procedure including a CURSOR function.

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you need to use Dynamic SQL, you can form the query for individual table and `UNION ALL` the result

```
declare @sql    nvarchar(max)

; with cte as
(
    < your cte query> 
)
select  @sql    = isnull(@sql + char(13) + 'UNION ALL' + char(13), '')
        + 'SELECT tbl_name = ''' + tbl_name + ''', COUNT(*) AS Records_missing'  + char(13)
        + 'FROM ' + quotename(tbl_name) + ' AS a'                                + char(13)
        + 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ('         + char(13)
        + 'SELECT *'                   + char(13)
        + 'FROM  table_a b'            + char(13)
        + 'WHERE a.COLUMN = b.COLUMN)' + char(13)
from    cte 

print   @sql
exec    sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: That's a clever way of suppressing the initial `Union All`.

Comment: Wow!... that is truly amazing. Serves me perfectly. Thank you.